# Exception: edit an excel file with XLWINGS while user interaction

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I'm using ***xlwings*** to manage my data into excel files.
I create a new *book* and save it into class object `self.app_file`.

```
self.app_file = xw.Book()
self.app_file_name = '{} - WorkFile.xlsx'.format('Progetto')
self.app_file.save(self.app_file_name)
self.worksheet = self.app_file.sheets[0]
```

Then the program reads some data and put it into this new file.
It runs perfectly. No errors at all.
**HOWEVER**, if i click or do any stuff on this excel file while the script is running, it raise this undefined error:

```
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Eccezione.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2146827284), None)
```

Now, I searched it everywhere and I found that Excel Api gives priority to user input over the code. It's ok but i want to update cell in real time while the user is working on the file.

Here is the full message error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\excel\app.py", line 369, in <module>
    engine.add_files(['Example file 2.xlsx']).update().format()
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\excel\app.py", line 269, in format
    file_group_column.value, file_group_column.color, file_group_column.api.Font.Color = self.lst_group_all_files, self.colors['DRK'], rgb_to_int((255, 255, 255))
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\xlwings\main.py", line 1957, in color
    self.impl.color = color_or_rgb
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 1086, in color
    self.xl.Interior.Color = rgb_to_int(color_or_rgb)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 109, in __setattr__
    return setattr(self._inner, key, value)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 493, in __setattr__
    self._oleobj_.Invoke(*(args + (value,) + defArgs))
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Eccezione.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2146827284), None)
```

The exception starts from the first line of color modification. In fact the cells `A1` and `B1` are correctly changed even if the user is editing the file.
So cell value can be changed, color not.

Here is the extracted part of the code:

```
self.worksheet['A1'].value, self.worksheet['B1'].value = 'GROUP', 'KEY'

file_group_column = self.worksheet.range('A2:A{}'.format(len(self.main_file_data)+1)).options(transpose = True)
file_key_column = self.worksheet.range('B2:B{}'.format(len(self.main_file_data)+1)).options(transpose = True)
--> file_group_column.value, file_group_column.color, file_group_column.api.Font.Color = self.lst_group_all_files, self.colors['DRK'], rgb_to_int((255, 255, 255))
file_group_column.api.Borders(1).Weight, file_group_column.api.Borders(2).Weight, file_group_column.api.Borders(3).Weight, file_group_column.api.Borders(4).Weight = 2, 2, 2, 2
```

`-->` *is where the exception starts*.

The reason I'm escluding I wrote it wrong is the fact that if there are no interaction from the user, it does exactly what it should.

How can I do it?
I can use an other library if xlwings can't handle it.
Please help me I'm going mad.